# Help showing the closure of open neighborhoods is a closed neighborhood in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

In $\mathbb{R}^n$ I'm trying to prove that the closure of an open neighborhood $N_r(x) = \{y : d(x,y)<r\}$ is a closed neighborhood where $\bar{N}_r(x) = \{y : d(x,y)\leq r\}$ denotes the closed set  and $\overline{N_r(x)}$ denotes the closure.

To show that $\overline{N_r(x)} \subset \bar{N}_r(x)$ I have that as $\overline{N_r(x)}$ is the smallest set containing $N_r(x)$ and $N_r(x) \subset \bar{N}_r(x)$ then it follows that $\overline{N_r(x)} \subset \bar{N}_r(x)$.

However to show $\bar{N}_r(x) \subset \overline{N_r(x)}$ I'm having a difficult time show how to prove this. Should I take a set $N_{r}(x) = \{y:d(x,y) = r\}$ and say that as this set contains all the points on the boundaries, then I just need to show that there exists elements from both sets $\overline{N_r(x)}$ and $\bar{N}_r(x)$ in that set?

Any advice in the right direction would be gratefully appreciated

Comment: There's a confusion between $\bar N_r (x)$ and $\overline {N_r (x)}$. If you can tell me which one of these is the closure, and which is not, then we can clarify things together and answer your question.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг $\bar{N}_r(x)$ is the closed neighborhood while $\overline{N_r(x)}$ is the closure. I'll make an edit and be more specific.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarification. The rest of the question is excellent.

Comment: Ok, so, first and foremost, what is your definition of closure? (complement of open set, or in terms of sequences?) (It will help if you know both).

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг the closure of a set E is defined such that $\bar{E}$ = E $\cup$ E` where E` is the denotes the set of all limit points of E

Comment: Perfect. Can you think of what are the limit points of the open ball? (You know the answer, you should get the closed ball. Therefore, you must show that each point on the boundary of the open ball, is a limit point. Can you think of how to do this?)

Comment: okay so i can show that there exists another point $z \in N_r(y)$ thus $y$ is a limit point and in the closure and as the set contains all its limit points it is closed as well?

Comment: I apologize, I am unable to understand what you have done so far. I think you took $y$ on the boundary of the open ball, and if you take any ball around $y$, it will intersect the open ball at some point. This shows that $y$ is a boundary point. Would you like me to elaborate?

Comment: Ah i see now, my mistake. That's precisely what I wanted to do! I understand now

Comment: Excellent. So we've got through this together. Nevertheless, if you have any doubts, do clarify them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do 2 things: note that $\overline{N}(x,r) = \{y : d(x,y) \le r\}$ is indeed closed, by proving the complement is open (using the triangle inequality).

Then $\overline{N(x,r)} \subseteq \overline{N}(x,r)$ follows,as the left hand side is the smallest closed set containing $N(x,r)$ and $\overline{N}(x,r)$ is *a* closed set containing it.

You then need to argue that any point in $\overline{N}(x,r)$ is in this closure. The only non-trivial case occurs when $d(x,y) = r$, otherwise $y \in N(x,r)$ already . This one can see by showing that such $y$ are limits along the radius of the ball of points from $N(x,r)$.